# No three same in row

Tags: java, arrays

Task:  Given an integer denoting the size of the array.Fill array with integers.
 Return true,if the array contains three of same elements not next to each other.
 Return false,if the array not contains three of same elements,or contains but next to each other.

```
 public static boolean noThreeInRow(int [] array){

     for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
         if(array.length < 3) System.exit(0);
          if(array[i] != array[i+1]){
              return true;
          }else return false;
     }return true;
}
```

I can't solved this problem.Someone could help me?I am very beginner!

Comment: `if(array.length < 3) System.exit(0);` doesn't need to be in the loop, and doesn't need to exit the JVM. If the length is less than 3, there are no 3 in a row: return true.

Comment: Can you do 2 in a row?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

try using a counter and two loops to compare each number.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
    if(array.length < 3) System.exit(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++){
             if (array[i] == array [j+2]) counter ++
    }
return true
}return true;
```

Try something like that. But you will have to figure out how to deal with the numbers before `array[i]` during the `j` loop. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I do not understand what are you talking about.